# better way to test Css editor for manual tester

Tags: css, manual

There is an **editor** like **cKEDITOR**.

In which give content in **ckeditor** and **design** it same way there is an editor where user can put up their **`CSS`** in particular block which in return gives output .

How to test these **CSS**  editor??

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? If the question is, how can I test an editor where you input some CSS and it returns some output, the only answer you can expect is: input a lot of CSS. I'm sure we can do better than that.